# sed 'p;n' – Can't find any logic behind this sed command

Tags: sed

Case 1:

```bash
% seq 4 | sed 'p'
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
```

Because `-n` is not stated, *sed* prints every line by default, and reprints again because of the `p` command. This, I understand well.

Case 2:

```bash
% seq 4 | sed -n 'p'
1
2
3
4
```

This one seems very logical to me too. Do not print by default, unless explicitly stated by `p` command. So, no duplicates, as expected.

Case 3:

```bash
% seq 4 | sed 'p;n'
1
1
2
3
3
4
```

Because there's no `-n` option, I understand *sed* should print all lines by default. Later, `p` command should reprint every line. Then, `n` command reprints out again the pattern space, clears it and reloads next line. So, if my focus is on line number 1, I should see `1` printed three times, instead of twice.

I'd like to know how *sed* works for this particular case.

Comment: Btw: option `-n` and command `n` have a different function. See `man sed`.

Comment: Use the `--debug` option to see how GNU sed treats each command.

Comment: @protong THAT is a really fantastic option. Thank you!

Comment: @Cyrus It's worth to remind the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sed should print all lines by default. Later, p command

The line is not printed on input. It is printed on the end of the script, right before reading the next line. `sed 'p;n <here>'`

Sed works like this:

- First line is loaded in pattern space.
- Then `p` prints the pattern space.
- Then `n`:

  - Prints the *current* pattern space (unless `-n`)
  - Loads the next (second) line in pattern space.
- Then script ends, so:

  - Pattern space is printed (unless `-n`)
  - Then the next (third) line is loaded
  - and the script starts again.

So in the first example:

> sed prints every line by default, and reprints again because of the p command

No, first `p` prints the pattern space, *then* sed automatically reprints the pattern space and loads the next line. The "re-"printing is done on the end of the script, not by `p` command.

Let's throw some reference https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html emphasis mine:

> -n
>
> Suppress the default output (in which each line, **after** it is examined for editing, is written to standard output). [...]
>
> [...] If no commands explicitly started a new cycle, **then at the end of the script** the pattern space shall be copied to standard output (except when -n is specified) and the pattern space shall be deleted. [...]